# If statement ignored in mysql/php script?

Tags: php, mysql

My variable sqlConditions is only suppose to append when the user inputs text for that field.  I put "if(isset($_POST['example']))" to check for this, however this doesn't appear to stop each variable from appending.

For example:  if the user only inserts text in the "lastname" field, the $query variable should return:

```
 UPDATE students SET lastname = whateveruserputin
```

However, it looks like this:

```
 UPDATE students SET lastname = test , firstname = , major = , gpa =
```

How can I fix this!?  I would really like to get this code working.  Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
//connect to server

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$id=$_POST['id'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$color=$_POST['color'];
$number=$_POST['number'];

    //need id to be filled and need at least one other content type to change
    if(empty($id) || empty($lastname) and empty($firstname) and empty($color) and empty($number))
{

        echo "<font color='red'>Invalid Submission. You did not enter an ID or did not input an additional form element.  </font><br/>";

}

else // if all the fields are filled (not empty)
{   

$sqlConditions = array();

   if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){
    $lastName = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sqlConditions[] = 'lastname = ' . $lastName;
    } else {
    $lastName = '';
    }

if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){
    $firstName = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sqlConditions[] = 'firstname = ' . $firstName;
    } else {
    $firstName = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['color'])){
    $color = filter_var($_POST['color'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sqlConditions[] = 'color = ' . $color;
    } else {
    $color = '';
    }

if(isset($_POST['number'])){
    $number = filter_var($_POST['number'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sqlConditions[] = 'number = ' . $number;
    } else {
    $number= '';
    }
print $sqlConditions;

$query = 'UPDATE students SET ' . join (' , ', $sqlConditions);
print $query;

    insert data to database     
    //$query = mysql_query("UPDATE students SET lastname = '$lastname', firstname = '$firstname', color = '$color', number = '$number'
    //WHERE id = '$id'");
    //if (!query)
    //{
    //die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    //}


    // Close connection to the database
    mysql_close($con);

}

 }
```

Comment: <font color='red'>... that brings me back...

Comment: A variable can be *set* yet contain an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isset` isn't enough; add a `!empty` check as well, e.g.:

```
if(isset($_POST['lastname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname'])
```

**Edit**
Also, in order for the comment in your code to be a better reflection of what you want, your `if` statement should probably be:

```
//need id to be filled and need at least one other content type to change
if(empty($id) && (empty($lastname) || empty($firstname) || empty($color) || empty($number))
```

---

Here's your code with some improvements<sup>*</sup> and amendments regarding your comment about adding quotes to the strings:

```
<?php

//connect to server

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$id=$_POST['id'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$color=$_POST['color'];
$number=$_POST['number'];

    //need id to be filled and need at least one other content type to change
    if(empty($id) && (empty($lastname) || empty($firstname) || empty($color) || empty($number))
    {
        echo "<font color='red'>Invalid Submission. You did not enter an ID or did not input an additional form element.  </font><br/>";
    }
    else // if all the fields are filled (not empty)
    {   
        $sqlConditions = array();

        if(isset($lastname) && !empty($lastname)){
            $lastName = filter_var($lastname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $sqlConditions[] = "lastname = '" . $lastname . "'";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $lastName = '';
        }

        if(isset($firstname))
        {
            $firstName = filter_var($firstname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $sqlConditions[] = "firstname = '" . $firstname . "'";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $firstName = '';
        }

        if(isset($color) && !empty($color))
        {
            $color = filter_var($color, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $sqlConditions[] = "color = '" . $color . "'";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $color = '';
        }

        if(isset($number))
        {
            $number = filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $sqlConditions[] = "number = '" . $number . "'";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $number= '';
        }
        print $sqlConditions;

        $query = 'UPDATE students SET ' . join (' , ', $sqlConditions);
        print $query;

        //insert data to database     
        //$query = mysql_query("UPDATE students SET lastname = '$lastname', firstname = '$firstname', color = '$color', number = '$number'
        //WHERE id = '$id'");
        //if (!query)
        //{
        //die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        //}

        // Close connection to the database
        mysql_close($con);
    }
}
```

<sup>*</sup><sub>Since you already define all your `$_POST` items to variables, there's no need to keep going back into the collection.</sub>

Comment: +1 However, you could actually just use `if (!empty($_POST['lastname']))` as `empty` automatically suppresses any warnings for variables that aren't set.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you happen to know how I could add quotes to each item being appended.  I need UPDATE students SET lastname = 'whateveruserputin'instead of UPDATE students SET lastname = whateveruserputin

Comment: `$sqlConditions[] = "lastname = '" . $lastName . "'";` or better: `$sqlConditions[] = "lastname = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($lastName) . "'";`

Comment: You can just do `$sqlConditions[] = "lastname = '$lastName'";` to achieve that result. Note use of double quotes.

Comment: @webbiedave, is the `mysql_real_escape_string()` still needed after the `filter_var(.., FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` ? I think that may actually be problematic since characters will be double encoded.
i.e., instring=`"'"`, `filter_var yields` `"\'"`, `mysql_real_escape_string()` will then yield `"\\\'"`

Comment: @Eljakim: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` deals with making strings safe for use in HTML. It has nothing to do with making it safe for SQL. For example, `filter_var("jay's", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` produces `jay&#39;s`

Comment: Thank you all!!  One last question, how would I include WHERE id = '$id' in my $query variable?

Comment: @ShawnaMurat -- As per normal, after sanitising it with `intval()` though much better would be to use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Right now I have $query = mysql_query("'$query ' . WHERE id = '$id'"); but this doesn't seem to work...I run the script but nothing updates.

Comment: @ShawnaMurat -- if `$id` is set to a valid record but you're not doing any actual update (i.e. nothing gets updated because none of the fields get changed), then this is by design and unless you change your connection's [flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.constants.php#mysql.client-flags), specifically `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS`, your query will "fail" if nothing is updated.

Comment: @stealthyninja Thanks :) Is it possible to see an example of what I should do?

Comment: @ShawnaMurat -- that's a very broad question; I suggest you break it down a little and post some new questions / do some searches on SO and then start a new question(s) and hopefully webbiedave and some others will answer you and point you in the best direction. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this coding practices:

```
$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($lastName);
$sqlConditions[] = "lastname = '$lastName'";
```

Will resolve your problem even if the variables are empty... and make a little more secure your code to SQL injection attacks (very recommendable!!!)

Comment: No. This is not proper advice. Avoid `addslashes`. Always use the database provided mechanism for escaping (in her specific case, `mysql_real_escape_string`, but really she should be using PDO with parameterized queries).

Comment: @webbiedave OK, good point. But the this user seems need a fast help. Otherwise we could encourage her to use a framework (for example)

Comment: @NomikOS -- agreed on a framework, but first we must learn to walk and then we run. I think learning the "why"'s first-hand is essential before picking up something that might obscure actual PHP from you.

Comment: @stealthyninja I accepted the suggest to use mysql_real_escape_string, that's good point. And I totally agree with you about learn the why's indeed my comment about "fast help" is due to the proposition of use PDO. Of course it would be better but the practice of apply an escaping function is enough for now to put her in the right direction (and introduce her to the SQL injection concept). So we are cool. o/\o

Answer (score 0):

In the else fragment you are only checking if the variable is set but the variable is set but maybe  is empty.

Isset() checks if a variable has a value including False , 0 , or Empty string but not NULL.

Empty() function checks if the variable has an empty value empty string , 0, NULL ,or False.

Example:

```
<?php
 $var = 0;

 if (empty($var)) {
  echo 'it is empty since it has value 0 ';
}
if (isset($var)) {
 echo '$var is set though it is empty';
}
?>
```